# Parent entity failed to deploy

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout

I'm trying to use the metadata api to do a destructive change call on all non-packaged components in my sandbox.

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
layouts/SocialPost-Social Post Layout.layout(SocialPost-Social Post Layout):Parent entity failed to deploy
```

**Update**

I found it: *This layout is associated with enabling `Social Contacts` I went ahead and disabled social contacts temporarily, but it still came down with the page-layouts in the meta-data pull!*

Comment: I have had almost the exact same issue with the same profile. What I would probably suggest is exclude profiles from the deletion, 95% of the time I have an issue with metadata it's because of profiles

Comment: Did anyone answer this? I am getting same issue when trying to deploy a profile from one dev org to another dev org. Both the orgs are on Winter 13 so not sure why this would be an issue?

Comment: Ultimately I ended up just removing the layout from the sets of layouts that I download.

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I did....

I was receiving this error when trying to do a whole bunch of changes to my internal customized code base (uninstalled an unmanaged package which was basically a way of migrating stuff from another instance, but I was tired of it being coupled to this unmanaged package).

Here's how I dealt with them, one by one:

Save error: SocialPost : Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first    SocialPost.workflow

**Solution**: From your workspace filesystem, delete the SocialPost.workflow file.

Save error: Parent entity failed to deploy  SocialPost-Social Post Layout.layout    /1pel Sandbox/src/layouts

**Solution**: From your workspace filesystem, delete the "SocialPost-Social Post Layout.layout" file.

Save error: In field: layout - no Layout named SocialPost-Social Post Layout found  Admin.profile
**Solution**: From the profile XML metadata file, remove this section...

```
<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>SocialPost-Social Post Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>
```

Which can be done using ant:

```
<replaceregexp flags="sg">
    <fileset dir="src/profiles" />
    <regexp pattern="&lt;layoutAssignments&gt;\s+&lt;layout&gt;SocialPost-Social Post Layout&lt;/layout&gt;\s+&lt;/layoutAssignments&gt;" />
    <substitution expression=""/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Not sure why this is happening... too bad the Eclipse Force.com IDE isn't open source :-/

May The SForce Be With You!
youtube.com/MayTheSForceBWithYou

Comment: Good answer! Worked for me :)

Comment: BTW: The Eclipse Force.com IDE *IS* now open source!
https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore

Answer (score 3):

Here is another interesting option that I found when searching for the same error:

[Salesforce Ant Scripts Modification](http://blog.force365.com/2013/01/08/salesforce-ant-scripts-modification/)

Basically you update your Ant script to, using regex, strip out all the social post layouts, profile references, etc. from your codebase prior to deploying.

Comment: Very useful! Used the solution from that blog to remove some of the metadata which should either not be present on sandbox orgs (e.g. samlssoconfigs) or are related to a functionality not enabled on the org (e.g. Question.object and Answer.object when Salesforce Communities is not enabled).